# Quotation marks converted to entities in rolling back with summary

Tags: bug, status-completed, revisions-list, rollbacks, html-entities

In the revision history page of an answer, click "edit" next to an old answer, add an edit summary with an apostrophe (`'`) or double-quotation-mark (`"`) in it, and save without editing the post. The software will append "Rollback to revision [number]" to your edit summary (which is fine) and convert your quotation mark to the corresponding HTML entity displayed on the revisions list (which is a bug).

Example: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/593/revisions

Comment: I just had this issue as well: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/9437121/revisions

Answer (score 3):

The rollback comments were being html-encoded in the database, which is not how we usually store content.

This will be fixed going forward and I'll work on a fix for the existing bad content.