# Quotation marks are shown as HTML entities, in the revision page

Tags: bug, status-completed, revisions-list, encoding

It's a minor one.

In the [edit history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/75715/revisions) for [Why isn't Meta funny anymore?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75715) the quotation marks are not escaped. In the [revision page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/75715/2), the quotation marks are shown as HTML entities.

[image: screenshot]

I see this in Windows 7 32-Bit, using FireFox 10.0.2 (unsupported?).

Comment: No repro on Win7 64-Bit, FF 10.0.2. Or perhaps I'm not looking at the same page? I see the one on the left screenshot, not the right.

Comment: @ShawnChin, click on the permalink "chain" icon (4th icon below the "2")

Comment: Direct link [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/75715/2).

Comment: Of course, silly me. Confirm repro with FF 10.0.2 on Win 7 and Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: Confirmed on Chrome Canary 19.0.1047.0, Chrome 17.0.956.3, IE 9 all on Windows 7 64-bit. I think we're reasonably certain it's a double-escaping issue :)

Comment: For linking purposes, there's a [similar issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121153/quotation-marks-converted-to-entities-in-rolling-back-with-summary) when rolling back.

Comment: I can see this also with Safari 5.1.3 running on Mac OS X 10.7.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build, > `rev 2012.2.24.1231`.