# International characters (ñ, á , í) used on prompts / email subject on Stack Overflow en español are shown as HTML entities

Tags: bug, status-completed, localization, html-entities, spanish-stackoverflow

This isn't the same as [Quotation marks are shown as HTML entities, in the revision page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/123001/289691) because occurs on different UI elements and on a localized site.

The email that requests email confirmation on the registration as new user process on **Stack Overflow en español** using an email/password is not shown properly. It is shown as:

`Completar registro en Stack Overflow en espa&#241;ol`

instead of **Completar registro en Stack Overflow en español**

This string is in Transifex and use a variable for the site name.

The same happens on the prompt text shown after clicking on the button **¡Esto resolvió mi problema!** (This solved my problem) when a question is marked as possible duplicate of another one.

[image]

(taken from https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1863/65)

`Esto marcar&#225; tu pregunta como un duplicado, lo que redirigir&#225; a futuros lectores hacia la pregunta original y evitar&#225; que se publiquen futuras respuestas aqu&#237;.`

instead of **Esto marcará tu pregunta como un duplicado, lo que redirigirá a futuros lectores hacia la pregunta original y evitará que se publiquen futuras respuestas aquí.**

This string [is in Transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-es/translate/#es/english/138947141?q=key%3Aef58b05d363b24e35fcd8af9ea6f5e85) and it doesn't use variables.

Original reports on Stack Overflow en español Meta

- [Completar registro en Stack Overflow en espa&#241;ol](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3407/65)
- [Alerta muestra texto no decodificado al hacer clic a botón "¡Esto resolvió mi problema!"](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3287/65)

Comment: All characters are "international characters". They're only "non-international characters" if you don't use them in your nation, and still that designation only applies to people of your nation :P Calling ñ, á and í "international" is incorrect for swathes of users, and is an Anglocentric thing to say. I'm sure this was not deliberate, as you are Mexican ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A fix for this is rolling out in the next build (`2020.1.7.35722`).