# International characters (ñ, á , í) used on prompts show as HTML entities in the profile page

Tags: bug, localization, html-entities, spanish-stackoverflow

While editing [one's profile in Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current), navigating to Site settings > Applications shows a list of connected aplications.

If you try to remove one of the authorisations, a prompt shows a confirmation text. It consists on the following string:

> Are you sure you want to disallow this application?

Whose translation to Spanish ([see in traducir.win](https://es.traducir.win/strings/4532)) is:

> ¿Estás seguro de que no deseas permitir esta aplicación?

However, the HTML entities are not properly handled and this is what I see:

> [image]
>
> `&#xBF;Est&#xE1;s seguro de que no deseas permitir esta aplicaci&#xF3;n?`

Can this be fixed so it shows properly?

Note a similar bug was fixed some time ago: [International characters (ñ, á , í) used on prompts / email subject on Stack Overflow en español are shown as HTML entities](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309124/209901).